# Tensorflow: Read jpg's in various directories

Tags: tensorflow

I want to read all jpg's stored in subdirectories within another directory ('all_image_dir'). The subdirectory names are like '001', '002', etc.

It's not a problem to read all jpg's in a certain directory, for example 'all_image_dir/001, using:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once('all_image_dir/001/*.jpg'))
```

To access all jpg's in all directories, I tried something like this:

```
 filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once('all_image_dir/*/*.JPG'))
```

But this is not working... - how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The `pattern` pattern parameter to `tf.train.match_filenames_once` is rather limited. For your particular case, suppose your subdirectories are `001`, `002`, ... `020`. You can do the following to achieve the same effect as `'all_image_dir/*/*.JPG'` :

Get the files in 001, 002, etc. separately in terminal

```
ln -s folder1 1
ln -s folder2 2
...
ln -s folder20 20
```

Then:

```
all_files = [tf.train.match_filenames_once(
    'all_image_dir/%03d/*' % x) for x in range(20)]
# Concatenate the list of all the files before passing to string_input_producer
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.concat(all_files, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I discovered further (subsub-)directories within the now accessible subdirectories: for example 'all_image_dir/101/various_name_dir/*.jpg. Unfortunately, these directories are not named (respectively enumerated) in a simple way, but have various names... - is there a general way to handle this situation?

Comment: Just wanted to mention, that I've moved all jpg's to one directory by using ubuntu terminal. Practically, the problem is solved...

Comment: if you don't have enough images to overflow the capacity of files/folder of the underlying FS... otherwise, it won't work...